# Why gnu extension cleanup work with no parameter

Tags: c

Recently, I am reading [article](https://snai.pe/posts/c-smart-pointers) about using cleanup attribute in gnu C to implement smart pointer in C++.

```cpp
#define autofree __attribute__((cleanup(free_stack)))

__attribute__ ((always_inline))
inline void free_stack(void *ptr) {
    free(*(void **) ptr);
}
```

And using example:

```cpp
int main(void) {
    autofree int *i = malloc(sizeof (int));
    *i = 1;
    return *i;
}
```

My questions are:

- Why we don't need to pass parameter into `free_stack`?
- Why `free(*(void **) ptr)` work? I have no idea why it cast into `void**` and de-reference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html) is the definition of this attribute:

> `cleanup (cleanup_function)`
>
> **The cleanup attribute runs a function when the variable goes out of
>   scope**. This attribute can only be applied to auto function scope
>   variables; it may not be applied to parameters or variables with
>   static storage duration. **The function must take one parameter, a
>   pointer to a type compatible with the variable**. The return value of
>   the function (if any) is ignored.

You don't need to pass parameters to `free_stack()`, because it will be called whenever that automatic variable goes out of scope with pointer to that variable as an argument.

Since you are allocating memory with `malloc()`, you will have a pointer which you need to free. Hence the argument that is passed to cleanup function is **pointer to pointer (or `void**`)** in reality, then you need to use `(*(void**)ptr)` to reach the pointer you need to free. In your code, you can think that the following code runs when `i` goes out of scope:

```
free_stack(&i);
```

**Update:**

Just remember that cleanup function does not mean freeing memory. it means cleanup. For example, you can have following cleanup method to close a file when out of scope:

```
#define autoclose __attribute__((cleanup(auto_close_file)))

__attribute__ ((always_inline))
inline void auto_close_file(void *ptr) {
    fclose(*(FILE**) ptr);
}

int main(void) {
    autoclose FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    fputs("Hello World", fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't the function defined as `void free_stack(void **ptr)` right away, or even `void free_stack(void **int)`?

Comment: @thebusybee because that function declaration will be generic and can be used to free different pointer types. assume that you want to use same `autofree` to free a `char` and a `int`, so using `int **ptr` will not be proper. for why not defined as `void**`, I guess you can say that in the declaration of cleanup function it is defined that the function take a **pointer to variable**. if you use `void**`, you are saying that "*I'm passing pointer to pointer of variable.*" which is not correct. so it is better to use generic pointer `void*` and cast it to correct data type which is pointer here.

Comment: OK, understood the issue with `int **`, even though multiple cleanup functions can be defined. That does not add to the code size due to inlining, but looks cleaner and adds to the source size. -- For the `void **` I'm hesitating to agree, because the pointer is immediatly cast to that type. Why not use that upfront? The pointer to the compatible datatype *is* a pointer to a pointer, isn't it? The variable `i` happens to be of type `int*`, or the compatible `void*`, resp.

Comment: @thebusybee Remember that a cleanup function does not mean freeing memory. assume that rather than cleanup method which frees allocated memory by `free()`, you are writing a cleanup method that unlocks a mutex by `pthread_mutex_unlock()`. In that case, you need to use `(pthread_mutex_t*)ptr` to get required pointer and as you see, it is not double pointer. So if you would like to have a generic function declaration for cleanup function, it is better to use `void*` as argument. It is similar to thread's argument.

Comment: Sure, each `cleanup` function is free to do what is necessary to clean up. BUT, if I define a clean-up function like `free_stack()`, which should be named `free_heap()` BTW, and assign it via the attribute to a variable of type `int*`, I would expect its parameter to be a pointer to this type, that is `int**`. And equally, if I define a clean-up function like `auto_close_file()` for a variable of type `FILE*`, I would expect its parameter to be a pointer to this type, that is `FILE**`. -- It is a matter of correct type usage. There is no *requirement* to use `void*` at all.